# Interchanging the sides of a Heegaard splitting

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose that $M$ is a closed orientable connected $3$-manifold and that $M = U \cup V$ is a Heegaard splitting of $M$ (i.e. $U$ and $V$ are both handlebodies with a common boundary).  What are some necessary/sufficient conditions for there to exist a homeomomrphism $h : M \to M$ where $h(U) = V$ and $h(V) = U$?

Comment: Look at the induced map on the Heegaard surface. The Heegaard surface has a set of $\alpha$ curves representing the discs you glue in to get the first handlebody, and similarly with the $\beta$ curves. What you're asking, then, is when (given such a decoration) there's an automorphism of $\Sigma$ that sends the isotopy class of the collection of $\alpha$ curves to the isotopy class of the collection of $\beta$ curves. This is probably extremely hard to answer, though perhaps still algorithmic.

Comment: To further reduce the above: Isotopy classes of curves on a surface are determined by their (free) homotopy class. So this is now an algebraic problem. "Given a set $\alpha$ of $g$ conjugacy classes of elements of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$, and another set $\beta$, is there an automorphism that takes one to the other?" This is almost certainly an algorithmic question.

Comment: @Mike Miller. The family of conjugacy classes correspond to a disjoint family of simple closed curves on the surface that cut it down to a planar surface.  There could be lots of different families of curves that are a complete set of meridian disks for the same handlebody, so you need to keep track of exchangeing curves that don't change the handlebody.  I don't think this problem is amenable to the techniques you are suggesting.

Comment: Is the homeomorphic supposed to be orientation preserving or reversing?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman Yeah, you're right. Thanks for that point.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, your question can be translated into a group theoretic criterion, expressed in the mapping class group $\text{MCG}(S)$ of the surface $S = U \cap V$; this is the group of homeomorphisms of $S$ modulo the normal subgroup of homeomorphisms isotopic to the identity.

A homeomorphism $h : M \to M$ which swaps the two sides $U$ and $V$ restricts to a homeomorphism $\Phi : S \to S$. Furthermore, if one considers all homeomorphisms $\Phi : S \to S$, the ones that extend to a side-swapping homeomorphism of $M$ are invariant up to composition by homeomorphisms of $S$ isotopic to the identity. Thus your question can be equivalently reformulated as follows:

- Question: What is a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $\phi \in \text{MCG}(S)$ that is represented by the restriction of a side-swapping homeomorphism of $M$?

Let $\text{MCG}_U(S) < \text{MCG}(S)$ denote the subgroup of all mapping classes that are represented by the restriction to $S$ of a homeomorphism of the handlebody $U$ (this is a well-studied subgroup of $\text{MCG}(S)$, used by Masur, Canary, and others in understanding hyperbolic structures on handlebodies with applications to the proof of Thurston's ending lamination conjecture). Similarly denote $\text{MCG}_V(S)$. These two subgroups are conjugate in $\text{MCG}(S)$: the set of conjugators is represented by the restrictions to $S$ of homeomorphisms $U \mapsto V$. Furthermore this set of conjugators is a left coset of the normalizer $N_U < \text{MCG}(S)$ of $\text{MCG}_U(S)$ which I'll denote $N^V_U$. Similarly let $N^U_V$ denote the left coset of the normalizer $N_V < \text{MCG}(S)$ of $\text{MCG}_V(S)$ represented by the restrictions to $S$ of homeomorphisms from $V \mapsto U$. Notice that $(N^U_V)^{-1} = N^V_U$.

- Answer: $N^V_U \cap (N^V_U)^{-1} \ne \emptyset$