# Heegaard Splittings of Non-orientable 3 manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

A well known and oft-utilized fact from 3-manifold topology is that all closed, orientable 3-manifolds admit Heegaard splittings.

I am trying to understand what the appropriate notion of Heegaard splitting for a closed, nonorientable 3-manifold should be, assuming I want lots of familiar facts to carry over to this setting. I'm also curious about the interaction with the orientable case.

In particular, some things  I am pondering include:

> Given a closed, nonorientable 3-manifold $Y$,
>
> 1) Can one decompose $Y = H_{1} \cup_{\Sigma}H_{2}$, for some surface $\Sigma \hookrightarrow Y$, and some (possibly nonorientable) handlebodies $H_{1},H_{2}$ ?
>
> 2) Can one decompose $Y = \Sigma \coprod \tilde{H}$, for a one-sided surface $\Sigma \hookrightarrow Y$ and an open handlebody $\tilde{H}$?

And in the same vein as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035252/interchanging-the-sides-of-a-heegaard-splitting) question:

> 3) Can one realize $Y$ as a quotient $M/h$ of a free, involutive, orientation reversing homeomorphism $h:M \rightarrow M$ of an orientable 3-manifold $M$, where $h$ exchanges the two sides $U,V$ of some Heegaaard splitting $M= U \cup V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the proof of Theorem 1 in [J. H. Rubinstein. One-sided Heegaard splittings of 3-manifolds](http://msp.org/pjm/1978/76-1/pjm-v76-n1-p18-s.pdf): While he proves a slightly different theorem than in your question, I think, his argument will yield what you want. The nontrivial mod 2 cohomology class that he is using will be replaced by the canonical element of $H_2(M,Z_2)$ Poincare-dual to the element of $H^1(M,Z_2)$ which sends each orientation-reversing 1-cycle to $1\in Z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to part 1, you can definitely realize a non-orientable $3$-manifold as a union of two possibly non-orientable handlebodies. Just triangulate the manifold and take a regular neighborhood of the $1$-skeleton. This will be your first handlebody. The second handlebody is the closure of the complement. The fact that the second space is a handlebody is not as easy to see, but follows in the same way as the orientable case.

For number 3, you can definitely find an $M$ such that your manifold is a quotient by a free involutive homeomorphism. This is called the orientation double cover. Moreover, you can simply lift your two handlebodies in the quotient to handlebodies in $M$. You know that at least one of the handlebodies has a connected cover, otherwise $M$ would be disconnected. But then its boundary is connected, implying the other handlebody is connected as well.

I'm not sure about number 2. Seems unlikely in general.

Comment: This is great, but I'm going to leave this open a little longer in case someone can answer number 2. I had the orientation double cover in mind; one point I'm still not understanding about your response is why the nontrivial deck transformation should swap the lifts of the handlebodies of the splitting of the base that you described?

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. My construction will not swap the two handlebodies.

Answer (score 0):

Considering question 2) let me exemplificate a 3-manifold which can be splitted along an orientable surface:

Let $N_3$ be the nonorientable genus three surface.
Take $E=N_3\times S^1$. Since $N_3=T_0\cup_C M\ddot{o}$, where $T_0$ is a puntured 2-torus, $M\ddot{o}$ is a Möbiusband and 
$C=\partial T_0=\partial M\ddot{o}=T_0\cap M\ddot{o}$ then
$E=(T_0\times S^1)\cup_U (M\ddot{o}\times S^1)$, where $U$ is the 2-torus 
$C\times S^1$.

But one can consider $M\ddot{o}\times S^1=\overline{{\cal N}(C\ddot{o}\times S^1)}$ (a regular neighbourhood and has, as aconnected boundary, another 2-torus) where $C\ddot{o}$ is the core of $M\ddot{o}$.

Then $E=(T_0\times S^1)\cup \overline{{\cal N}(C\ddot{o}\times S^1)}$. That is 
$$E\smallsetminus{\rm int}{\cal N}(C\ddot{o}\times S^1) =T_0\times S^1.$$

That is, $C\ddot{o}\times S^1$ (an orientable surface) is splitting $E$ within $C\ddot{o}\times S^1$ and $T_0\times S^1$ both orientable.

Comment: Such a torus $C\ddot{o}\times S^1$ is called Stiefel-Whitney surface for $E$.